# How to get the user entered data from view to controller and then insert into database, in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am a beginner and currently started a small project for my study purpose. A mini DB search portal. I created front end View. It has one search box and a button. Now what I need is, I have to fetch the data from DB, related to the user entered search term on clicking on the button.

How to proceed to get the user entered data from view to controller and process it for further operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General code:

**view:**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search","Test"))
{
  <input type="text" name="txtName"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Generate report" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HTTPPost]
public ActionResult Seacrh(FormCollection form) // "Search" is action name specified in view for controller "TestController"
{
    string text = form["txtName"]; // txtName is name of input in view.
}
```

However to take full advantage to `MVC` have a look at [Model Binding in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search), it has an example different ways of adding search.

You can update the Index method in your Controller and View as follows:

1)Add a form to the view that will post to the view itself
View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){    
     <p> Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />   
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p> 
    }
```

2)Add a parameter to the Index method to filter the content based on the parameter passed. `public ActionResult Index(string searchString)`

Controller

```
var movies = from m in db.Movies 
              select m;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) 
{ 
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)); 
}

return View(movies);
```